# ssl address mismatch on purchased ssl cert

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

i've bought a "Protect 1 Website" ssl from godaddy
http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx

, and requested and downloaded a cert for domain "example.com", but when i access dev.example.com, the browser url bar display a error "ssl address mismatch", i'm wondering if i access www.example.com (the www.example.com is point to another server now), will this error still occur?

Comment: Could you give some more information about the certificate? Is this a wildcard certificate, does it have SAN's, what's the issued to address?

Comment: it is not a wildcard

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that you've bought a non-wildcard certificate for the domain name `example.com`, and it doesn't work when you use it to access the domain `dev.example.com`, and you're surprised?  Have I understood correctly?

Comment: I'm afraid your certificate is not as all inclusive as you wish it to be, you'll need a wildcard for what you want to do. I suggest reading: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ssl-certs-guide/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subdomains are not included. If you want to protect subdomains take a wildcard certificate or purchase a certificate for the subdomain.

Comment: The only exception might be that most certificates these days include the www.example.com alternative name without extra cost. So your access to www.example.com might still be OK.

Comment: You can find that out easily by looking at the certificate